# How to receive control notification from Apple TV remote

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer, apple-tv

The iOS app is using AVPlayer and can play video on Apple TV, but app can't receive Apple TV remote control notification. For example, when user presses pause button on remote control, the local app should get this and change button to pause state. I have set the player controller as first responder.

Comment: please refer this link it will be helpfull to you. https://github.com/trentrand/Apple-TV-Remote

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't look like what I want. But still thanks

Answer (score -1):

Override 'pressesEnded' in your MainViewController:

```
override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        if(press.type == UIPressType.PlayPause) {
            // do what you want
        } else {
            super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
        }
    }
}
```